# Android startActivityForResult

Tags: android, listview

I'm using startActivityForResult, but I have no data, why? with this code I lunch the activity

```
conto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_new_conto);
conto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Mov.this,onto.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

and with this code I pass the value:

```
  lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);
             Intent intent=new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra("conto", d.conto);
                 setResult(2,intent);
finish();
```

with this code I get the value:

```
protected void onActivityResult1(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                          if(requestCode==2){
               if(null!=data) { 
                  conto.setText(data.getStringExtra("conto"));
```

Comment: "...but I have no data,... " Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: you didn't post the code where you receive the value ...

Comment: To clarify: Show your onActivityResult() method.  If you don't have one, write one.

Comment: At first the setResult method should be called like this: `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);`. Also post your `onActivityResult` code.

Comment: @vorrtex no you are wrong. The first paramter is an int value

Comment: Is your onActivityResult1 a misspelled name? It should not has the number 1 on its name

Comment: why do you have onActivityResult1 ?

Comment: @blackbelt I always right, here as well, the first parameter should be `Activity.RESULT_OK` and not `2`.

Comment: what does "I always right" mean. Still you are wrong. You can put the int value you want. It will be received as resultCode in onActivityResult. Please read the documentation @vorrtex

Comment: @blackbelt `You can` doesn't mean `you should`. The first parameter of `setResult` is `Activity.RESULT_OK` or 2 other constants, not "any int value".

Comment: you wrote "At first the setResult method should be called like this". It is like you are telling him that it does not work because the first parameter is 2 instead of Activity.RESULT_OK. @vorrtex

Comment: ok guys, so how can I?

Comment: ok, this question was offropic anyway. @user2856560 replace your `onActivityResult1` and see answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the started activity you just have to call `setResult(int)` and then `finish()`. In the calling activity you catch the result in `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`

Read more about this in the [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

ActivityForResult is an asynchronic call.
You should override `onActivityResult()` from your initial Activity, there you will get the result of the second Activity.

Inside your second Activity you should call `setResult()` method, continued by `finish()`

Comment: why asynchronic ? Also, what does asynchronic mean?